# Anyone know how to create 1024x1024 icns icons in Snow Leopard? Apple is now requiring 1024x1024 icons, and they're Lion only

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

Im having trouble submitting a quick update to my app to the mac appstore because apple now requires everyone to submit a 1024x1024 icns icon which is Lion only. Anyone know a way to create those icons in Snow Leopard? Read in another question that someone did it with hex edit, i'd be thankful should anyone provided a way to make these icons.

thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [create 1024*1024 icns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596776/create-10241024-icns)

Answer (score 2):

While it is true that on Snow Leopard **Icon Composer 2.2** can save files with 1024x1024 pixel icons, if those .icns files are used in an xcodeproject, the app will be rejected by the App Store.

Currently, the only solution I have found that works is to create a .iconset folder on Snow Leopard, move the .iconset to a Lion machine, convert the iconset to .icns using icnsutil on Lion.  And then move the .icns file back to Snow Leopard and include in xcode build.  Build and Archive.  Then Share and Save to Disk: move the .pkg file to Lion and upload with Application Loader.

That worked successfully for me.

Am currently investigating use of libicns.sourceforge.net.  If anyone works out another solution, would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this issue on Snow Leopard about creating an icns file containing 1024x1024 image.

I have been able to generate one using png2icns utility. It comes with libicns and is fairly simple to install.

You will first need to download Jasper at : http://www.ece.uvic.ca/~frodo/jasper/

Also you need libpng. I found it on Softpedia.

Build first jasper, libpng then libicns. To do so , for each of them I just add to cd into the directories where they are unpacked and , from the command tool type the commands :

```
./configure;
make;
sudo make install;
```

Then should should have png2icns available on the command line.
To use it, just cd to the directory containing your images and type :
 png2icns iconfile.icns image1.png image2.png......

Answer (score 1):

I built an app to make this easy. Drag your icon or icons to the app and it builds the .icns file for you.

If you only have a 512x512 icon, then it will scale that up automatically to 1024x1024.

Icns Builder https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/icns-builder/id554660130?mt=12

it's just a wrapper around the command line tools, but is a lot easier than scaling your own images manually